# How do I draw an image inside an Android master-detail app?

Tags: java, android

I'm new to android, so bear with me. Yesterday I started up an Android Master Detail project (Default Settings), and started looking around. I located a few lines of code nside com.myname.appname.ItemDetailFragment that looked like they were what was doing the changing of text in the secondary window. The related code is

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_detail,
                container, false);

        // Show the dummy content as text in a TextView.
        if (mItem != null) {
            ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.item_detail))
                    .setText(mItem.descrip);
        }
        return rootView;
    }
```

I want to change this code around so that instead of displaying text it draws an image on the secondary activity. Any suggestions

Also, since I'm new to android, any good tutorials on master-detail app programming, activities, drawing images, or just plain Android would be great.

Comment: The Android Developer website has stacks of good information and the samples you installed with the SDK answer all of your questions.

Comment: I suggest you buy a book. I find it easier to learn something completely new by one big example with explanations than looking at sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to declare ImageView view in your Layout and then  use the setImageDrawable or setImageBitmap methods to set Image on that view.

Tutorial on using ImageView can be found here:
http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-imageview-example/

Actually this tutorial explains how you can work with ImageView class.

Specifically for your case you need to locate the TextView under 'R.layout.fragment_item_detail' xml file. Probably the best place to declare your ImageView is where your TextView is, so you can replace your TextView with ImageView.

Then in your code you will have to inflate your ImageView similar to the TextView.

So it should look something like this:

```
  ImageView iv = ((ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.item_image))//you will have to use item_image as the id in your xml
```

use the appropriate methods to set Image/icon on your ImageView object. This will be explained in the tutorial.

Comment: when I put in the lines declaring the ImageView (from the site you linked me) in the res/layout/fragment_item_detail.xml Eclipse gives the following error " The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed. " Help? Also, what do you mean by "my xml?" As I said, I'm new...

Comment: your xml is not correct, please share your fragment_item_detail.xml file so that I can see what the error is

Comment: [Here's a pastebin.](http://pastebin.com/eG2RCVms) Also, how would I integrate this with a Canvas? (sorry If I'm pushing your patience)

Comment: Is that the contents of whole xml file? if yes then the problem is  that it is not contained within a ViewGroup (Layout). So I have modified your xml so use this and see if it now complains: http://pastebin.com/UiucapWi

Comment: Yaay, it works! I had to change the xml id, but that's no fault of yours. One last question (I swear). How does the ItemDetailFragment.java know it is bound to /res/layout/fragment_item_detail ? I see no mention of xml files in ItemDetailFragment.java or ItemDetailActivity.java

Comment: Good to hear that it has solved your problem. Please accept the answer. 
It is a good question infact and the answer lies in below line

View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_detail,
                container, false);
when the rootView object is returned from your onCreateView method the  container knows that the view has been inflated from this xml file: R.layout.fragment_item_detail